# Subdomain repoint

Tags: linux, centos, subdomain

I have a server with a subdomain - http://sub.example.com, and we have a client that wants to map one of their subdomains to ours.

We are running centos.

My understanding is that the client has to create a cname record that points from their subdomain to http://sub.example.com.

However, I am not sure if I need to actually do anything on my side to enable this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They need to create a CNAME that points to sub.example.com (without any http or anything).

If you run Apache on your server, you then need to add an [ServerAlias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#serveralias) with the domain name of your client to the vhost that should handle these requests.

Comment: Beaware that it won't like doing this with https, as certificates only work for a single domain.

Comment: OK, this need to work with SSL - what needs to happen in this case?

Comment: [Server Name Indication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) works for newer clients.  If you have older clients (such as IE 6) and you care about the warning they get then you will need another IP address.